# VBA: getHTML as custom function - Avoid several HTML retrivals

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping, custom-function

I am using this to retrieve HTML from a webpage

```
Function GetHTML(url As String) As String    
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .Send
        GetHTML = .ResponseText
    End With

End Function
```

I have created another custom function (fromthewebpage) to extract info from the HTML and put it into an 2d array.

```
Function fromthewebpage(month,user)
    testtext=GetHTML("http://example.com")
    ....
    ....
    fromthewebpage= udarray(month,user)
End function
```

When I need the info in the sheet I recall it with =fromthewebpage(x,y) in a cell.

But the size of the array is 13*4 and I need the whole array and each use of the fromthewebpage(x,y) function call GetHTML independently, resulting in 52 retrievals of the page. Are there ways to only call GetHTML once and reuse that info for each use of fromthewebpage.

I imagine either 1) calling GetHTML when opening the workbook and storing the info in a persistent array that I can reference when using fromthewebpage or 2) making fromthewebpage an array function. But I don´t know if that is possible and how to do it.

Comment: You would need a default URL as otherwise how are you going to pass an URL to GetHTML on workbook open (prompt?) ?  How are you doing to update that URL when you want to change it? Can you provide an actual URL and the full fromthewebpage function with example call and expected results? It doesn't sound like a UDF is the ideal way to go. Why can't you use a sub to deliver the array results to the sheet and then have your function access that area of the sheet? Or even better just use formulas?

Comment: You may just declare `udarray` variable as static within `fromthewebpage` function and store the array once you parse all the data. When call the function, first check if array is populated, and if no, parse the data.

Answer (score 1):

So, I mentioned in comments the idea of using a sub to retrieve the HTML info and returning your array to the sheet. You can then use a function or formulas to index into that info.

In the case below the sub picks the URL up from worksheet1 range A1. You could tie the sub to a button or a worksheet change event with target being A1 so updates when URL is changed.

The below is illustrative. I use StackOverflow question links to populate an array of what I believe to be your specified dimensions (easy to change though if not).

`GetHTML` returns the array to the sheet. The function `GetInfo` allows you to index into that array and return an item by specifying the row and column in the array. It is to mirror your specifying two arguments into a function signature to retrieve a string.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetHTML()
    Dim html As htmldocument, ws As Worksheet
    Set html = New htmldocument: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    On Error GoTo errhand
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", ws.[A1], False
        .Send
        html.body.innerhtml = .ResponseText
    End With

    Dim arr(0 To 13, 0 To 4)
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, c As Long
    Dim aNodeList As Object
    Set aNodeList = html.querySelectorAll("#question-mini-list h3 > a[href]")
    For i = 0 To (14 * 5) - 1
       If i = 0 Then
           arr(r, c) = aNodeList.Item(i)
       ElseIf i Mod 5 = 0 And i <> 0 Then
           r = r + 1: c = 0
           arr(r, c) = aNodeList.Item(i)
       Else
          c = c + 1
          arr(r, c) = aNodeList.Item(i)
       End If
    Next

    ws.[B1].Resize(UBound(arr, 1) + 1, UBound(arr, 2) + 1) = arr
errhand:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear
End Sub

Public Function GetInfo(ByVal r As Long, ByVal c As Long) As String
    GetInfo = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B1:F14").Cells(r + 1, c + 1)
End Function
```

---

**In sheet UDF call:**

[image]

---

**Worksheet_Change event**

If linking sub `GetHTML` execution to a `Worksheet_Change` event with URL in A1 then in sheet 1 code pane:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Address = [A1].Address Then
        GetHTML
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```